# Добавление слайдов в слайдер через Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Есть слайдер.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var carousel = $("#carousel").waterwheelCarousel({
      flankingItems: 3,

    });

    $('#prev').bind('click', function () {
      carousel.prev();
      return false
    });

    $('#next').bind('click', function () {
      carousel.next();
      return false;
    });

    $('#reload').bind('click', function () {
      newOptions = eval("(" + $('#newoptions').val() + ")");
      carousel.reload(newOptions);

      return false;
    });

  });


div id="carousel">
  <a href="#"><img src="http://www.cyberforum.ru/images/1.jpg" id="item-1" /></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://www.cyberforum.ru/images/2.jpg" id="item-2" /></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://www.cyberforum.ru/images/3.jpg" id="item-3" /></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://www.cyberforum.ru/images/4.jpg" id="item-4" /></a>

</div>
<a href="#" id="prev">Prev</a> | <a href="#" id="next">Next</a>
```

Пытаюсь изменять в нем слайды без перезагрузки страницы. 
Есть кнопки на сайте, нажимаю, отправляется запрос ajax, получает новые картинки (в консоли смотрю ответ)

```html
<div id="carousel3">
      
      <a href="#"><img src="http://wp2/lp/wp-content/themes/Uzor-treyd/images/5.jpg" id="item-5" /><
/a>
      <a href="#"><img src="http://wp2/lp/wp-content/themes/Uzor-treyd/images/6.jpg" id="item-6" /><
/a>
      <a href="#"><img src="http://wp2/lp/wp-content/themes/Uzor-treyd/images/7.jpg" id="item-7" /><
/a>
      <a href="#"><img src="http://wp2/lp/wp-content/themes/Uzor-treyd/images/8.jpg" id="item-8" /><
/a>
      <a href="#"><img src="http://wp2/lp/wp-content/themes/Uzor-treyd/mages/9.jpg" id="item-9" /></a
>
    </div>
    <a href="#" id="prev">Prev</a> | <a href="#" id="next">Next</a>
```

Но слайдер не работает.

Сделал кнопку для теста (Запускать функцию `carousel.reload();`). 
Жму на нее, но так же ничего не происходит.

В чем беда?

Вот сайт  [слайдера](http://www.bkosborne.com/jquery-waterwheel-carousel)

Comment: новые картинки вы как подгружаите в слайдер?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Почему именно такой? В чем смысл использовать JavaScript при написании слайдера? Можно сделать используя только HTML и CSS. http://codepen.io/drygiel/pen/rtpnE

```css
// CONFIG 

// Main
@border-size: 10px;
@slider-inner-width: 800px;
@slider-inner-height: 400px;
// CODEPEN: Did you know that if you put cursor (caret) in color #text and press [ALT] key you can choose color form picker?
@slider-main-color: #71ad37;
@slider-back-color: #3A3A3A;
@max-slides: 10;

// Dot
@dot-outer-size: 4px;
@dot-inner-size: 6px;
@dot-distance: 4px;
@dot-distance-top: 10px;
@dot-main-color: @slider-main-color;
@dot-back-color: @slider-back-color;

// Arrow
@arrow-type: 'lite'; // standard | lite
@arrow-size: 13px;
@arrow-distance: 15px;
@arrow-hover-shift: 0px;
@arrow-color: @slider-back-color;
@arrow-hover-color: @slider-main-color;

@speed: .5s;
@easing: cubic-bezier(.4,1.3,.65,1); // ease-out

.csslider {    
    -moz-perspective: 1300px;
    -ms-perspective: 1300px;
    -webkit-perspective: 1300px;
    perspective: 1300px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: @dot-distance + @dot-distance-top + 2 * @dot-outer-size;

    > input {
        display: none;

        .loopingClass (@index) when (@index > 0) {
            &:nth-of-type(@{index}):checked ~ ul li:first-of-type {
                margin-left: -100% * (@index - 1);
            }

            .loopingClass(@index - 1);
        }

        .loopingClass(@max-slides);
    }

    > ul {
        position: relative;
        width: @slider-inner-width + 2 * @border-size;
        height: @slider-inner-height + 2 * @border-size;
        z-index: 1;
        font-size: 0;
        line-height: 0;
        background-color: @slider-back-color;
        border: @border-size solid @slider-back-color;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;

        > li {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-size: initial;
            line-height: normal;
            -moz-transition: all @speed @easing;
            -o-transition: all @speed ease-out;
            -webkit-transition: all @speed @easing;
            transition: all @speed @easing;
            vertical-align: top;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            white-space: normal;

            &.scrollable {
                overflow-y: scroll;
            }
        }
    }
    
    > .navigation {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -2 * @dot-outer-size;
        left: 50%;
        z-index: 10;
        margin-bottom: -@dot-distance-top;
        font-size: 0;
        line-height: 0;
        text-align: center;
        .noSelect();

        > div {
            margin-left: -100%;
        }

        label {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            cursor: pointer;
            border-radius: 50%;
            margin: 0 @dot-distance;
            padding: @dot-outer-size;
            background: @dot-back-color;

            &:hover:after {
                opacity: 1;
            }

            &:after {
                content: '';
                position: absolute;
                left: 50%;
                top: 50%;
                margin-left: -@dot-inner-size;
                margin-top: -@dot-inner-size;
                background: @dot-main-color;
                border-radius: 50%;
                padding: @dot-inner-size;
                opacity: 0;
            }
        }
    }

    > .arrows {
        .noSelect();
        
        .goto-first,
        .goto-last {

        }
    }

    &.inside .navigation {
        bottom: @border-size;
        margin-bottom: @dot-distance-top;

        label {
            border: 1px solid #7e7e7e;            
        }
    }  
}

& {
    .repeat('.csslider > input:nth-of-type(  $i  ):checked ~ .navigation label:nth-of-type(  $i  ):after,');
    @{result} 
    {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.render-arrow();

.repeat(@pattern) {
    
    @to_repeat: ~'@{pattern}';
    @result: ~`(function(){ 
        var result = '';

        for(var i=1; i < @{max-slides} + 2; i++) {
            result += "@{to_repeat}\n"
                      .replace(/\s*\$im1\s*/g, i - 1)
                      .replace(/\s*\$ip1\s*/g, i + 1)
                      .replace(/\s*\$i\s*/g, i);
        }
        return result.replace(/[,\s]+$/,''); 
    })()`;
}

.noSelect() {        
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

/*#region MODULES */


.render-arrow () when (@arrow-type = 'lite') {
    @arrow-thickness: 2px;
    @arrow-thickness-hover: 3px;

    .csslider > .arrows {
        position: absolute;
        left: -@arrow-size - 3px - @arrow-distance;
        top: 50%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 2 * @arrow-size;
        padding: 0 @arrow-size + 3px + @arrow-distance;
        z-index: 0;
        -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
        box-sizing: content-box;

        label {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            top: -50%;            
            padding: @arrow-size;
            box-shadow: inset @arrow-thickness -@arrow-thickness 0 (@arrow-thickness - 1px) @arrow-color;
            cursor: pointer;
            -moz-transition: box-shadow .15s, margin .15s;
            -o-transition: box-shadow .15s, margin .15s;
            -webkit-transition: box-shadow .15s, margin .15s;
            transition: box-shadow .15s, margin .15s;

            &:hover {
                box-shadow: inset @arrow-thickness-hover -@arrow-thickness-hover 0 (@arrow-thickness-hover - 1px) @arrow-hover-color;
                margin: 0 -@arrow-hover-shift;
            }

            &:before {
                content: '';
                position: absolute;
                top: -100%;
                left: -100%;
                height: 300%;
                width: 300%;
            }
        }
    }   

    // Left conditions
    & {
        .repeat('.csslider > input:nth-of-type(  $i  ):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(  $im1  ),');
        .csslider.infinity > input:first-of-type:checked ~ .arrows label.goto-last,
        @{result}
        {
            display: block;            
            left: 0;
            right: auto;
            -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
            -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
            transform: rotate(45deg);
        }
    }

    // Right conditions
    & {
        .repeat('.csslider > input:nth-of-type(  $i  ):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(  $ip1  ),');
        .csslider.infinity > input:last-of-type:checked ~ .arrows label.goto-first,
        @{result}
        {
            display: block;
            right: 0;
            left: auto;
            -moz-transform: rotate(225deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(225deg);
            -o-transform: rotate(225deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg);
            transform: rotate(225deg);
        }
    }
}

.render-arrow () when (@arrow-type = 'standard') {
        
    .csslider > .arrows {
        position: absolute;
        left: -@arrow-size - @arrow-distance + 2px;
        top: 50%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 2 * @arrow-size;
        padding: 0 @arrow-size + @arrow-distance - 2px;
        z-index: 0;
        -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
        box-sizing: content-box;

        label {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            top: -50%;
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            border-top: @arrow-size solid transparent;
            border-bottom: @arrow-size solid transparent;
            border-left: @arrow-size solid @arrow-color;
            border-right: @arrow-size solid @arrow-color;
            cursor: pointer;
            -moz-transition: margin .15s;
            -o-transition: margin .15s;
            -webkit-transition: margin .15s;
            transition: margin .15s;

            &:hover {
                border-left-color: @arrow-hover-color;
                border-right-color: @arrow-hover-color;
                margin: 0 -@arrow-hover-shift;
            }

            &:before {
                content: '';
                position: absolute;
                top: -@arrow-size;
                left: -@arrow-size - @arrow-hover-shift - @arrow-distance;
                height: @arrow-size*2;
                width: 2 * (@arrow-size + @arrow-distance + @arrow-hover-shift);
            }
        }
    }

    // Left conditions
    & {
        .repeat('.csslider > input:nth-of-type(  $i  ):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(  $im1  ),');
        .csslider.infinity > input:first-of-type:checked ~ .arrows label.goto-last,
        @{result} 
        {
            display: block;
            left: 0;
            right: auto;
            border-left: none;
        }
    }

    // Right conditions
    & {
        .repeat('.csslider > input:nth-of-type(  $i  ):checked ~ .arrows > label:nth-of-type(  $ip1  ),');
        .csslider.infinity > input:last-of-type:checked ~ .arrows label.goto-first,
        @{result} 
        {
            display: block;
            right: 0;
            left: auto;
            border-right: none;
        }
    }
}

/*#endregion */



/*___________________________________ LAYOUT ___________________________________ */
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700|Lato);

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 2px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: rgba(74, 168, 0, 0.6);
}

ul, ol {
    padding-left: 40px;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    font: 400 100% 'Raleway', 'Lato';
    background-color: #282828;
    color: #CCC;
}

body {  
    padding-bottom: 60px;  
}

h1 {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 310%;
}

h2 {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 120%;
    color: #71AD37;
}

#slider1 {
    margin: 20px;
    font-family: 'Lato';
}

    #slider1 > ul > li:nth-of-type(3) {
        background: url(https://raw.github.com/drygiel/csslider/master/examples/themes/fruit.jpg);
    }

    // On Slide 3 Reached Event
    // Transition is added here to instantly hide when slide is changed 
    #slider1 > input:nth-of-type(3):checked ~ ul #bg {
        width: 80%;
        padding: 22px;
        -moz-transition: .5s .5s;
        -o-transition: .5s .5s;
        -webkit-transition: .5s .5s;
        transition: .5s .5s;
    }

        #slider1 > input:nth-of-type(3):checked ~ ul #bg div {
            -moz-transform: translate(0);
            -ms-transform: translate(0);
            -o-transform: translate(0);
            -webkit-transform: translate(0);
            transform: translate(0);
            -moz-transition: .5s .9s;
            -o-transition: .5s .9s;
            -webkit-transition: .5s .9s;
            transition: .5s .9s;
        }

    #slider1 > input:nth-of-type(6):checked ~ ul #dex-sign
    {
        -moz-animation: sign-anim @sign-duration .5s steps(@sign-frames) forwards;
        -o-animation: sign-anim @sign-duration .5s steps(@sign-frames) forwards;
        -webkit-animation: sign-anim @sign-duration .5s steps(@sign-frames) forwards;
        animation: sign-anim @sign-duration .5s steps(@sign-frames) forwards; 
    }

#bg {
    color: #000;
    padding: 22px 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 16%;
    height: 20%;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    overflow: hidden;
}
    // Blurry background
    #bg:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        left: -1px;
        top: 1px;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: -1;
        background: url(https://raw.github.com/drygiel/csslider/master/examples/themes/fruit.jpg) 1px 23%;
        -webkit-filter: blur(7px);
    }

    #bg:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 20;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    #bg div {
        -moz-transform: translate(120%);
        -ms-transform: translate(120%);
        -o-transform: translate(120%);
        -webkit-transform: translate(120%);
        transform: translate(120%);
    }

.scrollable p {
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: justify;
    line-height: 140%;
    font-size: 120%;
}

#center {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 25%;
  
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
      font-variant: small-caps;
    }
}
/*___________________________________ LINK ___________________________________ */
// More info here: http://codepen.io/drygiel/pen/hkgGq
a.nice-link {
    @color: @slider-main-color;
    @hover-color: lighten(spin(saturate(@color, 50%), -8), 8%);

    position: relative;
    color:  @color;
    h1 &:after {
        border-bottom: 1px solid @hover-color; // Underline
    }

    &:after {
        text-align: justify;
        display: inline-block;
        content: attr(data-text);
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        color: @hover-color;
        min-height: 100%;
        width: 0;
        max-width: 100%; // 'cause of IE bug
        background: @slider-back-color;
        -moz-transition: .3s;
        -o-transition: .3s;
        -webkit-transition: .3s;
        transition: .3s;
    }

    &:hover {
        color: @color; // To override default hover color

        &:after {
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
}

/*___________________________________ SIGN ___________________________________ */
// More info here: http://codepen.io/drygiel/pen/KbhmA
@sign-x: 255px;
@sign-y: 84px;
@sign-frames: 85;
@sign-duration: 3.5s;
@sign-total: @sign-frames * -@sign-y;

#dex-sign {  
  width: @sign-x;
  height: @sign-y;
  position: absolute;
  left: 33%;
  top: 45%;
  opacity: .7;
  background: url(http://www.drygiel.com/projects/sign/frames-255-white.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
  &:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-filter: ~'invert(30%) brightness(80%) sepia(100%) contrast(110%) saturate(953%) hue-rotate(45deg)';
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes sign-anim {
    to {
        background-position: 0 @sign-total;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes sign-anim {
    to {
        background-position: 0 @sign-total;
    }
}
@keyframes sign-anim {
    to {
        background-position: 0 @sign-total;
    }
}
```

```html
- var config = { 
-   count: 6,                // total count of slides in this slider
-   default_slide: 2,        // slide showed by default 
-   infinity: true,          // if true navigation arrows never disapears
-   inside: false,           // if true navigation dots apears inside of slider box
-   group_name: 'slides',    // each slider on page has to have another group name 
-   presentation_mode: true, // if false generates skeleton only
- }

if(config.presentation_mode) 
  h1(style="padding-top: 60px;") CSS Slider
  h2 Pure CSS Slider. No JS. Because it is possieble!

- var _list = new Array(config.count);
div.csslider#slider1(class=(config.inside? 'inside ':'') + (config.infinity? 'infinity':''))

    each _ , i in _list
      input(type='radio', 
            name=config.group_name, 
            checked=(config.default_slide == i+1), 
            id=config.group_name+'_'+(i+1))

    ul
      each _ , i in _list
        if(config.presentation_mode)
          li(class=(i==3? 'scrollable':''))
            case i
              when 0
                h1 Say hello to CSS3
                p CSSlider is lightweight & easy to use slider. No JS - pure CSS.
              when 1
                img(src='http://rawgithub.com/drygiel/csslider/master/examples/themes/stones.jpg')
              when 2
                div#bg
                  div
                    h1 CSS Events
                    p When slide 3 is reached - play CSS animation!
              when 3              
                h1 Lots of text
                h2 Scrollable one
                p.
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit fusce vel sapien elit in malesuada mi,
                  semper id sollicitudin urna fermentum ut fusce varius nisl ac ipsum gravida vel pretium tellus.
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit fusce vel sapien elit in malesuada mi,
                  semper id sollicitudin urna fermentum ut fusce varius nisl ac ipsum gravida vel pretium tellus.
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit fusce vel sapien elit in malesuada mi,
                  semper id sollicitudin urna fermentum ut fusce varius nisl ac ipsum gravida vel pretium tellus.
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit fusce vel sapien elit in malesuada mi,
                  semper id sollicitudin urna fermentum ut fusce varius nisl ac ipsum gravida vel pretium tellus.
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit fusce vel sapien elit in malesuada mi,
                  semper id sollicitudin urna fermentum ut fusce varius nisl ac ipsum gravida vel pretium tellus.
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit fusce vel sapien elit in malesuada mi,
                  semper id sollicitudin urna fermentum ut fusce varius nisl ac ipsum gravida vel pretium tellus.
              when 4
                div#center 
                  a.nice-link(href='https://github.com/drygiel/csslider', 
                              data-text='More examples on github',
                              target='_blank') More examples on github
              when 5
                div#center
                  a#dex-sign.play(href='http://drygiel.com', target='_blank')
              default
                | Slide #{i+1}
        else
          li Slide #{i+1}
          
    div.arrows
      each _ , i in _list
        label(for=config.group_name+'_'+(i+1))
      label(for=config.group_name+'_'+(1), class="goto-first")
      label(for=config.group_name+'_'+(config.count), class="goto-last")
      
    div.navigation 
      div
        each _ , i in _list
          label(for=config.group_name+'_'+(i+1))

if(config.presentation_mode) 
  a(href='https://github.com/drygiel', target='_blank')
    img(style='position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; border: 0;',
        src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/github/ribbons/forkme_left_darkblue_121621.png',
        alt='Fork me on GitHub')
```

Answer (score 1):

функция для кнопки reload должна быть примерно такой

```
$("#reload").on("click", function() {
   $("#carousel").load("test.htm", function() {
        carousel.reload({
            flankingItems: 3
        })
    });
    return false
   });
```

содержание условно test.html

```
<a href="#"><img src="http://www.umnet.com/pic/diy/screensaver/0/micky-2152.gif"  /></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://www.umnet.com/pic/diy/screensaver/0/micky-2152.gif" /></a>
```

плагин Waterwheel Carousel Version 2.3.0 содержит ошибку подгруженные картинки кликаться не будут, но сам слайдер и кнопки next и prev сохранят функциональность.